# Convert boolean to integer in elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there any cleaner way to convert **true -> 1** and **false -> 0** than resorting to

```
if boolean_variable do
  1
else
  0
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not aware of a built in conversion function for this. How you build your own solution depends on what you want to achieve. Consider your implementation:

```
def boolean_to_integer(bool) do
  if bool, do: 1, else: 0
end
```

If you recall that all values except `nil` and `false` evaluate to `true` in the context of a conditional expression, this has the effect that

```
iex> boolean_to_integer(0)
1
```

If this should be a problem, you can use a multi-clause function that only accepts booleans:

```
def boolean_to_integer(true), do: 1
def boolean_to_integer(false), do: 0

iex> boolean_to_integer(0)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in MyModule.boolean_to_integer/1
    iex:42: MyModule.boolean_to_integer(0)
```

Of course, you can extend this to your liking, for example to accept integers `0` and `1` as well as `nil` you can do:

```
def boolean_to_integer(true), do: 1
def boolean_to_integer(false), do: 0
def boolean_to_integer(nil), do: 0
def boolean_to_integer(1), do: 1
def boolean_to_integer(0), do: 0

iex> boolean_to_integer(0)
0

iex> boolean_to_integer(1)
1
```

Comment: Also [`case`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15.7/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#case/2): `case boolean do true -> 1; false -> 0 end`

Answer (score 8):

You can shorten it by using the following syntax, but as there is no explicit ternary operator in the language, an if macro is still required.

`if boolean_variable, do: 1, else: 0`

Source: [Elixir quick reference](https://github.com/itsgreggreg/elixir_quick_reference#ternary)

Comment: you could also do `boolean_variable && 1 || 0`. Not sure if t's cleaner though :)

Answer (score 0):

the shortest one:

```
boolean && 1 || 0
```